# LocalStorage for multiple fields with Angular2

Tags: angular, local-storage, web-storage

I am following this example: https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage
This works fine for me as boundValue is stored and I can retrieve it. However, I have a list of bots:

bot.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let bot of bots" 
        routerLink="/botlevelup/{{bot.id}}">
            <td>{{bot.id}}</td>
            <td>{{bot.lastLevel}}</td>
</tr>
```

botlevelup.component.html

```
Last Level: {{boundValue}}
<input [(ngModel)]="bot.lastLevel" />
```

botlevelup.component.ts

```
this.storage.store('boundValue', this.bot.lastLevel);
```

How can I make use of webstorage to store values for all of my bots?

Edit #1: I followed Tours of Heroes as well and I am able to change the values which only retains for the session.

Edit #2:
Original getBots snippet that display all bots:

```
  getBots(): Observable<Bot[]> {
      return this.http.get<Bot[]>(this.botsUrl)
      .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getBots', []))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly store it inside the local storage as  a object/array

just do it as follows,

```
this.storage.store('botsboundvalue', JSON.stringify(this.bots));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I changed to this line but nothing happens. Thank you! this.storage.store('boundValue', JSON.stringify(this.bots));

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens? it should store all the values of bots in your local storage

Comment: It is stored in local storage, reflected on botlevelup.component.html However, the value does not reflect on my bot.component.html where all the bots are listed.

Comment: you need to retrieve again and assign to this.bots = JSON.parse(this.storage.get('botsboundsvalue'));

Comment: Hi there, I am still unable to retrieve after adding this line in.. I have put up the code which I used to get all the bots. Thank you!

Comment: i dont understand why you are not able to get details if they are in the local storage

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I am able to get the details displayed at first. However after refreshing the page, the view reverts back to original state. But the new updates are still stored in the local storage.